# A subgroup $Z$ of $p$-adic integer such that $Z/pZ\neq C_p$.

Tags: algebraic-number-theory

This question may be weird in the sense that I am considering a subgroup of infinite index.

Let $p$ be a prime (let's say $p\neq 2$ although I'm not sure whether this assumption is needed) and we consider subgroup $\mathbb{Z}_p$, say $Z$, which contains $\mathbb{Z}$. Now I want to consider the group $Z/pZ$. For the obvious case, i.e $Z=\mathbb{Z}$ or $Z=\mathbb{Z}_p$, this group is isomorphic to cyclic group of order $p$, $C_p$. If $Z$ is smallest subgroup containing $\mathbb{Z}$ and a 'rational' number then $Z/pZ$ would be the same as before. However this doesn't seem to be true in general (for instance let $Z$ be a smallest subgroup containing $\mathbb{Z}$ and an irrational element). Would there be any classification of subgroup Z of $\mathbb{Z}_p$ such that $Z/pZ\cong C_p$? Or some broader property which $Z$ could have to make it true?

Motivation for this is an exercise of Neukirch in Algebraic number theory

Comment: @Arthur You sure about that? The equivalence class of $z \in Z$ would depend only on the $n+1$-th last digit.

Comment: @Arthur You don't seem to notice that we're looking at $Z/pZ$ and not at $\mathbb{Z}_p/Z$.

Comment: @McFry That's what I have been doing. I'm just being blind.

Comment: It didn't help that the OP confused the issue by using $Z$ as the letter for a subgroup of $\mathbb Z_p$ containing $\mathbb Z$ :) @Arthur

Comment: It appears I missed something. Notation I have used is from Neukirch so blame him for that. To be fair I really should have been clearer though.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$Z/pZ$ is always a vector space over $\mathbb Z/p\mathbb Z$. It is of dimension one if every two vectors are linearly dependent.

This means that if $z_1,z_2\in Z\setminus pZ$ then there are $1\leq a,b<p$ so that $az_1+bz_2\in pZ$, or, really, to simplify, you need $1\leq c<p$ so that $cz_1+z_2\in pZ$.

In particular, it is necessary that $Z\setminus pZ$ must have elements all of the same valuation in $\mathbb Z_p$, though that is far from sufficient.

If $Z$ contains $\mathbb Z$, then this condition means that given any element $z\in Z\setminus pZ$ of the form:

$$z=a_0p^0+a_{1}p^{1}+\dots\tag{1}$$

with $0\leq a_i<p$ and $a_0\neq 0$, then $a_{1}p^0+a_{2}p^{1}+\dots\in Z$.

Also, since all the elements of $Z\setminus pZ$ have the same valuation, then if $a_{0}=0$ in $(1)$ then $z\in pZ$ so $a_{1}p^0+a_{2}p^{1}+\dots\in Z$.

So, assuming $\mathbb Z\subset Z$, that ultimately means you need the one condition:

> $Z\cap p\mathbb Z_p= pZ$

This should be necessary and sufficient.

The general subgroup $Z$ of $\mathbb Z_p$ such that $Z/pZ\cong C_p$ (without necessarily containing $\mathbb Z$) is some multiple of the above sort of group: $Z=wZ_0$ for $w$ any non-zero element of $\mathbb Z_p$ and $Z_0$ some group containing $1$ and satisfying $Z_0/pZ_0\cong C_p$. So the above really is the heart of all such groups.

Comment: This is great! I honestly didn't expect any real nice classification. Was mostly hoping! Not sure whether this will actually help me out solving the exercise but I will certainly have a better chance now!